# Is Ubuntu Core for Raspberry Pi discontiued?

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

On Frontpage of Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi images Ubuntu Core is missing. But I am sure I used to get Ubuntu Core images from there. Is it discontinued?

Comment: It's not as easy to download ; https://ubuntu.com/core  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/20/stable/current/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it still exists

Details : https://ubuntu.com/core

Direct Download : https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/20/stable/current/